# Error no-restricted-syntax iterators/generator en Eslint Airbnb

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, ecmascript-6, bucles

Estoy probando Eslint usando las guías de estilo de Airbn, uso el paquete `airbnb-base`
Mi duda surge apartir de este error en un bucle `for..of`

```
error: no-restricted-syntax - iterator/generator
```

En la documentación dice:

> Don’t use iterators. Prefer JavaScript’s higher-order functions instead of loops like for-in or for-of.

y este es el porqué:

> Why? This enforces our immutable rule. Dealing with pure functions that return values is easier to reason about than side effects.

Podrían explicarme con un ejemplo ¿cómo ocuerre la mutación que mencionan usando otro tipo de iterador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo la explicación de airbnb, cuya guia de estilos estas usando. Supongo que sabrás que puedes negar algunas de las normas, poniendo el primer parámetro en 'off', en lugar de en 'error' o 'warn'. O incluso podrías mirarte el github de Airbnb, ver qué normas te interesan e ir incluyendo sólo esas una a una, de manera que controles mejor qué estilo quieres imponer.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// bad
let sum = 0;
for (let num of numbers) {
  sum += num;
}
sum === 15;

// good
let sum = 0;
numbers.forEach((num) => {
  sum += num;
});
sum === 15;

// best (use the functional force)
const sum = numbers.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0);
sum === 15;

// bad
const increasedByOne = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  increasedByOne.push(numbers[i] + 1);
}

// good
const increasedByOne = [];
numbers.forEach((num) => {
  increasedByOne.push(num + 1);
});

// best (keeping it functional)
const increasedByOne = numbers.map(num => num + 1);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo, lo pasé por alto en el repositorio de la guia, por lo que entiendo esta regla es sólo por la **preferencia del uso de programación funcional**. Y así evitar tener valores fuera del bucle que estén cambiando constantemente.